# How to increase timeout for activating features through Visual Studio deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, sharepoint-2010

I get the following error sometimes when deploying a SharePoint 2010 solution via Visual Studio 2010:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': A timeout has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process.

It's true -- it's taking a long time because we do a lot of work in the feature receiver. But **This is not an error; I would just like Visual Studio to wait longer**. Is there a place I can configure the amount of time to wait before timing out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ChannelOperationTimeout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee471440.aspx

Do not forget to restart Visual Studio